# How to merge paragraphs into parent link with jquery / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, merge, append

How do I turn this:

```
<a class="link">
   <p class="paragraph">This is some text</p>
   <p class="paragraph">This is some more text</p>
   <p class="paragraph">And some more</p>
</a>
```

into this:

```
<a class="link">
   This is some text This is some more text And some more
</a>
```

with jQuery. I tried using append and merge but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method returns the text content of an element and it's descendants, you can just use that:

```
var link = $("a.link");
link.text(link.text());​​​​​​​​​
```

From the docs:

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched
>   elements, including their descendants.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ehCVt/).

**Update** (see comments)

In the case that this needs to apply to multiple `.link` elements, you can use `each`:

```
$("a.link").each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text()); 
});
```

Comment: But what happens if `a.link` matches more than one element?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - Then it will replace the text of each with the text of all. I was assuming this would only apply to one element. See edit.

Comment: great, I actually do need it for multiple elements

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
$("a.link").text(function(i,text){
    return text;
});
```

And yet another way (not tested):

```
// you can optionally filter to
// only p elements too with
// .children("p")
$("a.link").children().contents().unwrap();
```

Here's another variation of the second:

```
$("a.link p").contents().unwrap();
```

**Edit:** Just a note for clarity:
All of these solutions work on multiple elements. The first solution is a relatively uncommon syntax that can be used on most jQuery setter functions. It runs the callback on each matched element and sets the value of the property/attribute to the value returned from the callback.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var concatText = "";

      $("p.paragraph").each(function(){
       concatText = concatText + " " + $(this).text() 
      });

        $("a.link").html(concatText);
​     });​
```